# how to add the elements of cstrings in c++?

Tags: c++

I wanna to add the elements of the string. for example is want to add a[5] and b[5] answer should be 11, how can i do it

```
#include<iostream>

#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string a="12345";

    string b="23456";

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It's impossible since your strings only have 5 length. You can access individual element like an array, so to add the the last elements do this cout << a[4] + b[4] - (2 * '0') << endl;

Comment: And what are you going to do with the result of the adding?

Comment: i have to make a LongInt class that can store 1000 digits and and addition and other operation can be applied on it

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that the valid range of indexes is [0, 4]. There is no element a[5] in string a.

You can do the task the following way

```
std::cout << a.back() - '0' + b.back() - '0' << std::endl;
```

Or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{

    std::string a = "12345";

    std::string b = "23456";

    std::transform( a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(),
                    std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ),
                    []( char c1, char c2 ) { return ( ( c1 -'0' ) + ( c2 - '0' ) ); } ); 
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string a = "12345";
    std::string b = "23456";

    std::string c;
    c.reserve( a.size() );

    int overflow = 0;
    std::transform( a.rbegin(), a.rend(), b.rbegin(),
                    std::back_inserter( c ),
                    [&]( char c1, char c2 ) -> char
                    {
                        int s = ( c1 -'0' ) + ( c2 - '0' ) + overflow;
                        return ( overflow = s / 10, s % 10 + '0' );
                    } );
    if ( overflow ) c.push_back( overflow );

    std::reverse( c.begin(), c.end() );

    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```